# How to format a string with several numeric variables?

Tags: powershell

I need a Write-Verbose to display several numeric variables in a compact way. It does work with one variable at a time:

```
Write-Verbose $A
Write-Verbose $B
```

I have more variables in a loop, and tried to place few of them on a single line, to get output like:

```
A: 12345   B: 67890
```

The spec goes a long way, and whatever I tried, doesn't work. Will appreciate a short example.
Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? ```Write-Verbose "A: ${A}`tB: ${B}"``` should do

Comment: Didn't work: outputs `VERBOSE: A:      B:'

Comment: Variables are defined as: $A = 1234

Comment: I can output them one by one, but how to format them together in a single string is beyond me :)

Comment: Actually, it worked, I am sorry and thank you! It shows simple variables all right. It doesn't work with variables, which are members of a class, like, $A = @{ X = 0 }, but there is a workaround: can assign them to simple ones and put n format statement

Comment: You're welcome :) It won't work with a hashtable, but any custom object will be shown with it's root-level properties: `$A = [pscustomobject]@{ X = 123 }; "A:${A}"`

Answer (score 1):

@Mathias,

How about this to write a hash table?

```
Function Test-HTVerbose {
  
   [CmdletBinding()]  

  $A = [Ordered]@{'Val1' = 1
                  'Val2' = 2
                  'Val3' = 3}
  
  
  Write-Verbose $($A | FT | Out-String)
}

$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
Test-HTVerbose -verbose
```

Sample Output:

```
VERBOSE: 
Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
Val1                           1                                               
Val2                           2                                               
Val3                           3
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for compact representation in a single line: it was working in a loop. Reassigning to simple variables worked just fine, and I completed the troubleshooting.